# ngClick function not working using 'controller as' method and not $scope

Tags: angularjs

Have just started using angular, and struggling to get ngClick to run.

I have stack overflowed most of the potential solutions but all refer to having to use $scope in order for to ngClick to work.

However, I am aware that you do not need this as long as the page you are on has the correct controller assigned to it (‘controller as’ method) and therefore as long as your function is within this controller it should work.

However, I am struggling to get my code to fire at all- no errors are coming back so I can debug.

Here is my setup as follows:

```
Angular version: 1.6.4
```

Router.js

```
state(‘exampleShow', {
  templateUrl: '/templates/example.html',
  controller: ‘exampleShowController as exampleShow'
})
```

controllers.js

```
exampleShowController.$inject = [‘Example’, '$state', 'User'];
function exampleShowController(Example, $state, User) {
 const exampleShow = this;

 function addExample() {
  console.log('click');
 }

}
```

example.html

```
<button ng-click="addExample()" class="u-full-width button-primary">Add 
example</button>
```

I know I'm missing a rookie error here, but seriously cannot spot what it is i am missing.

Thank you for any light that can be shed on this.

K

Comment: try `ng-click="exampleShow.addExample()"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use `controller as` syntax, So you need to bind your controller function to `this` and you have to call same by alias in `html` also., Like: `ng-click="exampleShow.addExample()"`

Demo:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('ExampleShowController', ExampleShowController);

ExampleShowController.$inject = [];

function ExampleShowController() {
  const exampleShow = this;
  exampleShow.addExample = function() {
    console.log('click');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.2/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ExampleShowController as exampleShow">
  <button ng-click="exampleShow.addExample()" class="u-full-width button-primary">Add example
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey man - thank you sooo much-great answer and easy to understand without using $scope!Can't believe I missed that but worked perfectly -  All the best!

Answer (score 0):

you did not inject `$scope` in your controller. Your ng-click function should be a part of scope if you want to use it in template